# Convert build.gradle wrapper / distributionUrl settings to build.gradle.kts

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

How do I convert this `build.gradle` code to `build.gradle.kts`?

```
// run ./gradlew wrapper whenever you change this
wrapper {
    distributionUrl("https://globochem.jfrog.io/artifactory/globochem-gradle/globochem-6.6.6.zip")
}
```

For this setup:

```
$ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.6
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-11-25 13:35:10 UTC
Revision:     daece9dbc5b79370cc8e4fd6fe4b2cd400e150a8

Kotlin:       1.7.10
Groovy:       3.0.13
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          11.0.18 (Homebrew 11.0.18+0)
OS:           Mac OS X 12.6.2 aarch64
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for `build.gradle.kts`:

```
// run ./gradlew wrapper whenever you change this
tasks.withType<Wrapper> {
    distributionUrl = "https://globochem.jfrog.io/artifactory/globochem-gradle/globochem-6.6.6.zip"
}
```